# Visual Studio UML designer - data types

Tags: visual-studio-2010, generics, types, uml

I'm using the Visual Studio UML designer to create some class diagrams. Since I would like to generate code from the diagrams it need to be accurate.

Now I'm trying to define the type of some properties of my classes, but I can't find a way to give them a type different from bool, string, int and UmlimitedNatural (and my own types of course). I found a [tutorials that claims](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/02/01/how-to-generate-code-from-a-uml-model-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) I would have to create custom stereotypes. Really? I mean it's VS, I'm just asking for some build in reference/value types like `byte` or `GUID`.

Do I overlook a hidden switch or if there is really now way to tell VS to bring up some commonly used types does anyone know a source for UML profiles that provide it? And how I can define more complex types like generics?

Comment: What happens if you just type in `Byte` or `Guid` in the type field?

Answer (score 0):

UML is implementation language neutral.  Since types differ by platforms it is necessary to define an implementation language profile for any UML tool.  Most UML CASE tools include the option to choose the language and apply a built in profile, which should make them available.